# Knockoutjs: Expanding the SimpleGrid to Support Sorting

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How would you modify the [knockout.js simpleGrid plug-in](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.js) to support column sorting?

I have got the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/NaveenVelaga/QSRBR/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a fiddle with the supplied code.

I have modified the simpleGrid code to expect a sorting function in the column data.
This way we can wire up the template to sort on click via the supplied function.

http://jsfiddle.net/QSRBR/39/

This is a simple solution which needs to be expanded to include bi directional sorting logic 
(second click sorts in reverse direction)

Comment: Sorting performed is not alphabetical sort instead it's ASICIbetical sort

Answer (score 3):

Use KnockoutSimpleSortableGrid found at https://shiljopaulson.github.io/Knockout.simpleSortableGrid/ and it contains samples in it

Comment: This is great.  I'm going to switch to using this.  Has anyone looked into refreshing columns data binding, so that these name/labels could be altered after initial creation of the grid view?  I'd like to see the column labels be observable.

Comment: that can be done by changing the columns variable to ko.observableArray please refer the https://github.com/shiljopaulson/Knockout.simpleSortableGrid/blob/master/sample02.html