# KnockoutJS: The SimpleGrid component

Tags: datagrid, knockout.js

I was thinking about building an advanced grid component (with features like reordering of columns, hide/show of columns, sorting, advanced filtering (on a per-column basis), etc). I would like to go with KnockoutJS for data-to-UI bindings (unless someone thinks it's a bad idea for some reason?).

Now, I know that there's [this basic grid example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.js) and I also found [this extension of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566774/knockoutjs-expanding-the-simplegrid-to-support-sorting), but more can be done with this thing. So I'm wondering if you've heard of anyone already working on such a grid? (So that I can contribute instead of re-inventing the wheel.)

Comment: The only one that I know of is here: https://github.com/RoyJacobs/mosdev.  Roy is blogging about it here: http://www.royjacobs.org/category/development/.  I think that he has put it on hold while KO 1.3 settles in.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, haven't seen it before.

Comment: Does RP Niemeyer's comment and Roy Jacob's grid solve your problem, or are you still looking?

Comment: After a quick look at Roy's grid I decided to go with another solution and started working on a jQuery plugin instead of KO component. Perhaps it's my KO skills (or lack thereof) but I find it easier to maintain such a complex component using the jQuery plugin model.

Answer (score 8):

Punchout Grid (https://github.com/EntitySpaces/Punchout#readme) may do what you want. It is "a fully HTML true Knockout control with both server side and client side paging, sorting, and more."  There are six example tables in the [Punchout Grid examples folder](https://github.com/EntitySpaces/Punchout/tree/master/examples).

Another possibility is [KoGrid](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid), "a Knockout DataGrid". See it in action at 
http://www.entityspaces.net/entityspaces.js/Examples/EntitySpaces/KoGridExample.htm .